# What's the difference between ffmpeg static libraries form ubuntu and from mine that I compiled?

Tags: apt, compiling, ffmpeg, libraries

I tried ffmpeg from ubuntu repositories and linking them was as easy as just doing `-lavcodec -lavuitl ...`. I then compiled mine with these configurations:

```
    ./configure \
    --prefix=${BUILD_DIR}/desktop/x86_64 \
    --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
    --enable-shared \
    --arch=x86_64 \
    --enable-vaapi \
    --disable-vaapi \
    --enable-opencl \
    --disable-debug \
    --enable-nvenc \
    --enable-cuda \
    --enable-cuvid \
    --enable-libvpx \
    --enable-libdrm \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --enable-libfdk-aac \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-openssl \
    --enable-pic \
    --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm -lz -ldl" \
    --enable-nonfree
```

And it generated static libraries just like those provided by ubuntu repositories. However, I cannot simply link them with `-lavcodec -lavuitl ...` because I get lots of undefined references, like

```
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): In function `fdk_aac_decode_frame':
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_Fill'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_DecodeFrame'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_GetStreamInfo'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): In function `fdk_aac_decode_close':
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0xf): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_Close'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): In function `fdk_aac_decode_init':
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x45): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_Open'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x82): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_ConfigRaw'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0xb7): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x129): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x187): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_AncDataInit'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x1ac): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x1d1): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x1f2): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x213): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x22f): undefined reference to `aacDecoder_SetParam'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o):libfdk-aacdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x250): more undefined references to `aacDecoder_SetParam' follow
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function `aac_encode_close':
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `aacEncClose'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function `aac_encode_frame':
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text+0x2c1): undefined reference to `aacEncEncode'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function `aac_encode_init':
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x3c): undefined reference to `aacEncOpen'
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x7c): undefined reference to `aacEncoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0xb8): undefined reference to `aacEncoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0xfa): undefined reference to `aacEncoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x180): undefined reference to `aacEncoder_SetParam'
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x25d): undefined reference to `aacEncoder_SetParam'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o):libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x28d): more undefined references to `aacEncoder_SetParam' follow
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function `aac_encode_init':
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x567): undefined reference to `aacEncEncode'
libfdk-aacenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x5a1): undefined reference to `aacEncInfo'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vpx_decode':
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_decode'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_frame'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error_detail'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_decode'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_frame'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_dx_algo'
libvpxdec.c:(.text+0x58f): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp8_dx_algo'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vpx_free':
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x9): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_destroy'
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x18): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_destroy'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vpx_init':
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x87): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_version_str'
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0xa5): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_build_config'
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0xdf): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_dec_init_ver'
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0xed): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vp8_init':
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x134): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp8_dx_algo'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vp9_init':
libvpxdec.c:(.text.unlikely+0x142): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_dx_algo'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vpx_encode':
libvpxenc.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_encode'
libvpxenc.c:(.text+0x2b3): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_encode'
libvpxenc.c:(.text+0x33a): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_cx_data'
libvpxenc.c:(.text+0x3cd): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_cx_data'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `log_encoder_error':
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x351): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x35c): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error_detail'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `codecctl_int':
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x43a): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_control_'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vpx_init':
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x4fb): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_caps'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x503): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_version_str'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x521): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_build_config'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x563): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_enc_config_default'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x573): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_err_to_string'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0xc2c): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_enc_init_ver'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0xc86): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_enc_init_ver'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0xffb): undefined reference to `vpx_img_wrap'
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x1040): undefined reference to `vpx_img_wrap'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vp8_init':
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x10be): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp8_cx'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vp9_init':
libvpxenc.c:(.text.unlikely+0x10d3): undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_cx'
../../../deps/ffmpeg/build/desktop/x86_64/lib/libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vpx_free':
...
```

How it it possible for ubuntu to not have to rely on `x264, libfdk-aacdec, libvpxdec, etc` but when I use my compiled libraries I have to provide them?

Comment: Have you tried to compile with `--disable-shared --enable-static` (instead of `--enable-shared`)?

Comment: Three small questions: 1. What version of FFmpeg did you compile? 2. Why: `  --enable-vaapi --disable-vaapi` ? 3. What application are you compiling against your FFmpeg installation?

Comment: Additionally, what are you trying to accomplish?  You've installed a shared ffmpeg  out of the ld & PKG_CONFIG paths.

Comment: @Meuchelfix77 I tried, but the compiled version still won't include the other libraries

Comment: @andrew.46 I compiled ffmpeg 4.2, ` --enable-vaapi --disable-vaapi` is just a typo, but I actually compild with this, but this is not the library that my code asks to. I'm compiling my own test application

Comment: @doug Iḿ tryint com compile an application that depends on ffmpeg but none of its shared libraries dependencies. I wanted to compile ffmpeg with all its dependencies as static, compiled together in the binary

Answer (score 2):

The newest [ffmpeg (7:4.1.3-0ubuntu1) for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/disco/ffmpeg) (disco dingo) (as of 2022, [ffmpeg (7:4.4-6ubuntu5) Impish](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/ffmpeg)) is available from the bottom of that webpage. Ubuntu uses the [Debian build process](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch04.en.html) for ffmpeg.

To build from sources *exactly* the same way as Debian or Ubuntu does you need to use "debmake" and "debuild". For complete documentation see the “[Guide for Debian Maintainers](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/index.en.html)” (2019-03-26) tutorial.

The "debmake" command doesn't "make" from source, it modifies the source. It is the "debuild" command that does the *making* (but not by directly using "make", instead "dpkg-buildpackage" is used).

The usual way to build from sources:

```
$ tar -xzmf debhello-0.0.tar.gz
$ cd debhello-0.0
$ make
$ make install
```

The *Debian* way to build from sources:

```
$ tar -xzmf debhello-0.0.tar.gz
$ cd debhello-0.0
$ debmake
  ... manual customization
$ debuild
  ...
```

You can pickup the source and build dependencies using:

```
sudo apt-get source ffmpeg
sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg
```

See Ubuntu's [apt-get help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) for details on using the command.

If you want your resulting build to be ***similar*** to what you would get from installing the package use "debmake" and *then* modify the files in the directory. After making modifications (that don't break anything) type "debuild" to create a *similar* executable (with your added or removed features). [Advanced examples](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch08.en.html) of this hacking are also available, see the guide for maintainers (3rd link from the top of this answer).

Try a simple example first (without modifying it), unless you feel comfortable with the above instructions. See also the [Debian Build Tutorial Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial).

There is also an explanation for Debian on our SuperUser site: [How to install FFmpeg on Debian?](https://superuser.com/a/865744/419485)